# How can I run child module plugin goal when I build the main project?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

#### how can I run child module plugin goal when I build the main project

I want to run spring-boot plugin after build the project, but the spring-boot plugin only added in the submodule, is there any solution? thanks always!

```
main-project
    pom.xml
        spring-boot plugin not added in the main pom.xml
    module1
        pom.xml
    module2
        pom.xml
            depend on module1
            spring-boot plugin added
```

when I run the command

```
mvn clean install -pl module2 -am spring-boot:run
```

the maven throws excption

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? And not just execute multiple times maven?

Comment: in you suggest i can build all module `mvn clean install` and then `cd module2` `mvn spring-boot:run` this can work, but i want to run the mvn command only once to run the spring-boot:run goal.

Comment: Why? if you do ````mvn clean install && cd module2 && mvn spring-boot:run```` you have all in one line too. I assume that your main project has a module section so it will build all modules.

Comment: great idea,  i only need to write command in one line, lol, thansk :-)

Comment: Great that you like my answer. I add this as an answer and I would appreciate it if you could accept this as the correct answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
mvn clean install && cd module2 && mvn spring-boot:run
```

you have all in one line too.

I assume that your main project has a module section so it will build all modules.

Comment: Better `mvn clean install` afterwards `mvn -pl module2 spring-boot:run`...